# Can I insert dictionaries with values list in a loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, mergeddictionaries

```
key, values
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 6)
(0, 7)
(1, 0)
(1, 2)
(2, 1)
(2, 0)
(3, 4)
(3, 5)
(4, 3)
(5, 3)
(6, 0)
(7, 0)
```

I have problem with my python code. I want to insert data in the dictionaries in python. I see error like this:

```
N = len(g.nodes())

label_for_node = dict((i, v) for i, v in enumerate(g.nodes()))
node_for_label = dict((label_for_node[i], i) for i in range(N))


communities = dict((i, frozenset([i])) for i in range(N))
dq_dict = {}
H = MappedQueue()

partition = [[label_for_node[x] for x in c] for c in communities.values()]

dq_dict = dict(
        (i, dict( (j)
            for j in [ node_for_label[u] for u in g.neighbors(label_for_node[i])] if j != i)) 
                    for i in range(N))

TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

The problem is I want to insert dict when index same with previous index. and I want to output like this:

```
{0: {1, 2, 6, 7}, 
1: {0, 2}, 
2: {1, 0}, 
3: {4, 5}, 
4: {3}, 
5: {3}, 
6: {0}, 
7: {0}}
```

[top up saldo paypal](https://jualsaldo.com)

Comment: There is no code provided here. If there is a problem with your code and you want help with it, you should show us your code.

Comment: How are you coming to the expected dictionary ? what's the logic ? Its not clear from your question. Please elaborate.

Comment: Do you have a list of tuples?

Comment: What is a `MappedQueue`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def dictify(data):
    result = dict()
    for key, value in data:
        if key in result:
            result[key].add(value)
        else:
            result[key] = set([value])
    return result
```

Example

```
>>> data
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 0), (7, 0)]
>>> dictify(data)
{0: {1, 2, 6, 7},
 1: {0, 2},
 2: {0, 1},
 3: {4, 5},
 4: {3},
 5: {3},
 6: {0},
 7: {0}}
```

You can also achieve this using `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
def dictify(data):
    result = defaultdict(set)
    for key, value in data:
        result[key].add(value)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 0), (7, 0)]
new_dict=defaultdict(set)
for k,v in l:
    new_dict[k].add(v)
```

---

```
defaultdict(set,
            {0: {1, 2, 6, 7},
             1: {0, 2},
             2: {0, 1},
             3: {4, 5},
             4: {3},
             5: {3},
             6: {0},
             7: {0}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary's [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method is built for exactly this purpose. It takes in two arguments, the key value, and the default value for the key if the key isn't inserted yet in the dictionary. It then returns the value corresponding to the key.

```
l = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 0), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 0), (7, 0)]
z={}
for k,v in l:
    z.setdefault(k,set()).add(v)
```

Comment: I code working, but why the set must be cardinal number?